Return an exception instead of throwing it
I've come across this piece of code
if (substr($this->method, 0, 2) == '__') {
    return new \Exception('Error: Calls to magic methods are not allowed!');
}

I've never seen a method returning an exception (instead of throwing) it and searching online for something similar doesn't yield any results.
Is there a difference between throwing and returning an exception? Is there any point in doing it?

The context is OpenCart and they're basically using exceptions as the stand-in for a return value that indicates an error. Though why on earth they would do this instead of actually throwing/catching the exception is beyond me.

Topical: How to pass thrown error back to the controller?


Is there a difference between throwing and returning an exception?

Absolutely. new Exception() simply creates an instance of an class, like any other use of new would. So return new Exception() doesn't raise an error, it's just returning an object.
The difference then becomes sort of like the difference between echoing a string or returning a string. When I do echo $string; I know the string is going to be output right away and there's nothing the caller can do about it. When I do return $string; then I'm giving that control back to the caller, who may then do whatever they want with the string -- echo it, save it to a database, further manipulate it, etc.
Likewise, when I do throw $exception; I'm expecting to raise an issue immediately. When I do return $exception I'm allowing the caller to deal with it however they like.

Is there any point in doing it?

There are cases where it's useful but you don't see it done very often because that concept of letting the caller deal with an error is already supported by the native behavior of try/catch.
